# Compress-Archive issue with TFS 2015

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

I m facing an issue with Compress-Archive cmd line. I need to compress drop files (some files) and push compressed .rar to Azure blob storage.

In VSTS we have default compress task & which does for me, but in TFS 2015 I m using powershell cmd

```
Compress-Archive -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\* -DestinationPath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

I ended up . with error

2018-06-26T17:29:08.5918176Z Generating script.
2018-06-26T17:29:08.5918734Z Formatted command: . 'D:\a\1\s\arch.ps1'
2018-06-26T17:29:09.3003116Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a_temp\e2b5fc08-c599-49ec-bbd6-8a4a69f8d977.ps1'"
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3345598Z Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory : The term 'Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3345966Z function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3346099Z path is correct and try again.
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3346952Z At D:\a\1\s\arch.ps1:5 char:47
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3347355Z + ... e -Path .* -DestinationPath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Buil ...
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3348520Z +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3348782Z     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExc 
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3348968Z    eption
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3349135Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
2018-06-26T17:29:14.3349466Z
2018-06-26T17:29:14.5676478Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

How can I access build variables within my powershell script ? could someone guide me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming you're using the newer build system introduced in TFS 2015, not XAML build.

Those values are stored as environment variables when running within a script.
They can be accessed as follows, as an example:
`$env:Build_ArtifactStagingDirectory`

Answer (score 1):

The error info is  **CommandNotFoundException** ,  you may using the wrong format of the command-- [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6) . Try to change the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(Build.BuildId).zip`

Besides about how to access Build variables in TFS, you should go through this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch) first.

[image]

If you want to use environment variable powershell scripts, you should use `$env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME` format.

Comment: Since I m using VNEXT, I had to use $env:Build_ArtifactStagingDirectory, and when I execute this CMD  "Compress-Archive -Path ${env:Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory} -DestinationPath ${env:Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory}\${env:Build.BuildId}.zip" It threw path is null or empty. so when I say write-host "$env:Build_ArtifactStagingDirectory" It gave me empty string. How can I debug ? do I need to manually create this variable ?